# Javascript Dropdown for ImageSelector

Tags: javascript

I've got an SQL database im doing some queries on and filling in a dropdown box with the code.

It's a select/combo box. It returns my database fields.

red 
black
green.

In the source code i modified the query to get a second field in the same table.
red.jpg
black.jpg
green.jpg.

How can i at runtime display a picture of a red shirt using the onChange() function in javascript? I found this online example useful javascriptkit .com/script/cut173.shtml

$interface is my sql query
pic1 is the image being changed
the html code looks like this
Choosered
green
black

heres the snippets. any help is greatly appreciated.
http://pastebin.com/mgqrEiJu

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.jsfiddle.net/FpNK4/) should solve your problem. Loop through all the records and print out `<option value="$url">$name</option>`

Comment: This is a great answer, the issue i have though is that im using one of the values that mysql returns as the data the form posts. It only works when i change my query to return the values first. But that stops my script from posting "RED", its posting "../images/red.jpg".

Comment: Here is what the query returns and prints to HTML.
<OPTION VALUE="../images/red.jpg" name="red">

Comment: try switching the 'value' and 'name' and change the function to say `imgtag.src=dropdown.getAttribute('name');`

Comment: its still not working :-(  i could post all the code on pastebin if you want to take a peek. What you've responded with looks correct but for some reason the javascript isnt getting the name element anywhere. I'm even printing up a popup box and its returning null.